# IN PHP MVC, can controller bypass model and use a data service itself?

Tags: php, model-view-controller

In PHP MVC, should a controller consult a model to get data requested by the user or is it good practice as well to have the controller use a data service class and get the data without calling the model? First method means excessive code in some cases, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

The service layer is not a core part of the MVC design pattern, but rather an addition. As such, if talking in purely MVC language, to interact with the database a `Model` class is necessary.

Actually, if `Service` classes are implemented correctly, then they are, as I already mentioned, an addition to the MVC, so they are not a replacement for the `Model` classes. The `Service` classes should work in a way that they take away logic from the `Controller` class and then they call the `Model` class in order to execute database operations.

Imagine if we are writing a CRUD for managing users. The `UserModel` class will contain methods for storing, fetching, deleting, updating data, etc. The `UserController` class will most likely accept requests from the views, perform validation, sanitize input, notify third parties if necessary, etc. This can become quite cumbersome and hard to follow. So, instead, we take away some logic from the `Controller` class and put it in a `Service` class. In our example with the user management, we will probably take away the input sanitization and the validation and perform it in the `Service` class. If everything is good the `Service` class will call the `Model` to perform database operation. And the only job of the  `Controller` class would be to call the `Service` class and notify third parties about the operation (if that was what we were building).

In conclusion, `Service` classes do not make `Model` classes obsolete, but rather they expand the MVC pattern to an MVCS pattern, where the request path looks like this:

View -> Controller -> Service -> Model and vice versa.

Comment: Hi. A note: validation should not take place in the service layer, but in the _entities_, e.g. most likely in what you name _models_.

Comment: @dakis Depends on the framework used. Some frameworks like Laravel do that kinda stuff in so called Request classes. CodeIginiter performs validation in the Controller classes. Pure MVC design pattern, by definition, doesn't enforce where the validation should happen, so it is left for interpretation by the developer. However, I am pretty confident when saying Controllers are better place to store such logic than models, since it doesn't have much to do with database manipulation (what models are for).

Comment: Just a thought: A _model_ about which you are speaking about is, actually, a mix of codes of an _entity_ (e.g. a _domain model_), a [_data mapper_](https://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html) and, probably, an [_active record_](https://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html) implementation. I think, a proper separation of responsibilities (in respect of SRP) should be made, in order to find the correct place for validation.